# Is it safe to reuse Spring Spel Expression instances?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-el

I will be evaluating a few Spel Expressions on a lot of different objects.

The Spring documentation greatly encourages to cache the `SelEvaluationContext`, but since I am using my expressions on different objects every time, I cannot cache it.

Therefore, I figured that I would at least cache the parsing / compilation of the `Expression` itself and use `getValue()` on different root object every time.

However, the expression only evaluates correctly the first time, but throws an exception the second time.

I reproduced the problem in the following test.
The code as-is throws an exception at the second or third iterations.
When I uncomment the line that parses the expression on every iteration, it works well.

It also works if I do not use the `SpelCompilerMode.IMMEDIATE` flag when creatng the parser, but that defeats the point of pre-creating all the expressions.

```
@Test
    public void testSpelExpressionReuse() {
        final SpelParserConfiguration specParserConfiguration = new SpelParserConfiguration(SpelCompilerMode.IMMEDIATE, this.getClass().getClassLoader());
        final SpelExpressionParser expressionParser = new SpelExpressionParser(specParserConfiguration);
        
        Expression spelExpressionCompiled = expressionParser.parseExpression("#root['hehe']");
        
        for (int i = 0; i < 50000; ++i) {
            //spelExpressionCompiled = expressionParser.parseExpression("#root['hehe']"); // WORKS WHEN UNCOMMENTED
            System.out.println(spelExpressionCompiled.getValue(Map.of("hehe", "hoho")));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to raise GH issue for Spring Framework: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues

We got an error like this:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: failed to access class java.util.ImmutableCollections$Map1 from class spel.Ex2 (java.util.ImmutableCollections$Map1 is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; spel.Ex2 is in unnamed module of loader org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelCompiler$ChildClassLoader @7fdd43cd)
    at spel.Ex2.getValue(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:189)
```

Looks like there is some problem with that `ChildClassLoader`.

The error happens already on a third iteration, just because a SpEL compilation logic is like that:

```
/**
 * Compile the expression if it has been evaluated more than the threshold number
 * of times to trigger compilation.
 * @param expressionState the expression state used to determine compilation mode
 */
private void checkCompile(ExpressionState expressionState) {
    this.interpretedCount.incrementAndGet();
    SpelCompilerMode compilerMode = expressionState.getConfiguration().getCompilerMode();
    if (compilerMode != SpelCompilerMode.OFF) {
        if (compilerMode == SpelCompilerMode.IMMEDIATE) {
            if (this.interpretedCount.get() > 1) {
                compileExpression();
            }
        }
        else {
            // compilerMode = SpelCompilerMode.MIXED
            if (this.interpretedCount.get() > INTERPRETED_COUNT_THRESHOLD) {
                compileExpression();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Probably it is going to work with Java 8 though where we don't have `modules` limitations yet...